# How to correctly configure Rails system tests with Rspec + Capybara and a dockerized Selenium Standalone Chrome?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, selenium-chromedriver, capybara, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm setting up CI with a Gitlab Runner for a Rails App with Rspec + Capybara and a dockerized image of selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0. The tests pass locally, but once they hit CI system tests fail with the error Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError.

I've tried running the tests locally but with the same dockerized image selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0, and the system tests fail with the error Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError.

## capyraba.rb configuration

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    if ENV['SELENIUM_URL'].present?
      # Make the test app listen to outside requests, for the remote Selenium instance.
      Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'

      # Specify the driver
      driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400], options: { url: ENV['SELENIUM_URL'] }

      # Get the application container's IP
      ip = Socket.ip_address_list.detect(&:ipv4_private?).ip_address

      # Use the IP instead of localhost so Capybara knows where to direct Selenium
      host! "http://#{ip}:#{Capybara.server_port}"
    else
      # Otherwise, use the local machine's chromedriver
      driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome
    end
  end
end
```

## Gitlab CI

```
image: starefossen/ruby-node:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules
    - vendor/ruby

services:
  - postgres:9.4.20
  - selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  RAILS_ENV: test
  DB_HOST: postgres
  DB_PORT: 5432
  SELENIUM_URL: 'http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub'
```

## stack backtrace

```
 1.1) Failure/Error: find('#map-spot-creation').click(x: 150, y: 500)

          Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
            no such session
              (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
            Command duration or timeout: 6 milliseconds
            Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
            System info: host: '03fdb0cca17d', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
            Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
            Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.VTiW5k}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3112.113, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
            Session ID: bbdeebbc74c3f543af5572cbe50c7f7f
            *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#map-spot-creation} (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException)



          # [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):-2:in `newInstance0'
          # [remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):62:in `newInstance'
          # [remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java):45:in `newInstance'
          # [remote server] java.lang.reflect.Constructor(Constructor.java):423:in `newInstance'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler(ErrorHandler.java):215:in `createThrowable'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler(ErrorHandler.java):167:in `throwIfResponseFailed'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):671:in `execute'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):437:in `findElements'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):505:in `findElementsByCssSelector'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector(By.java):441:in `findElements'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):398:in `findElements'
          # [remote server] sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12():-1:in `invoke'
          # [remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java):43:in `invoke'
          # [remote server] java.lang.reflect.Method(Method.java):498:in `invoke'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2(EventFiringWebDriver.java):104:in `invoke'
          # [remote server] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4():-1:in `findElements'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver(EventFiringWebDriver.java):177:in `findElements'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElements(FindElements.java):50:in `call'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElements(FindElements.java):35:in `call'
          # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask(FutureTask.java):266:in `run'
          # [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1(DefaultSession.java):176:in `run'
          # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):1149:in `runWorker'
          # [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):624:in `run'
          # [remote server] java.lang.Thread(Thread.java):748:in `run'
          # ./spec/features/user_creates_a_spot_account_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: You need to register a remote selenium driver to connect to the docker container - show your driver registrations.